# Plexiglass and 2.4GHz wifi signal

Tags: wireless

I have very simple question:

If device which uses regular WiFi (2.4 GHz) connection (i.e. USB receiver for wireless mouse or mobile phone) is put into plexiglass case, would that lower connection quality?

I've heard a lot of contradiction claims about it and I can't google anything that will confirm truth, so I hope someone can help.

Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Robert Wilson, a graduate student at USC, prepared [an analysis of 2.4GHz and 5GHz propagation through common materials](http://www.am1.us/Protected_Papers/E10589_Propagation_Losses_2_and_5GHz.pdf), with a useful Table 3. It looks like Plexiglas incurs about a .36dB loss at 2.3GHz and about a .93dB loss at 5.25GHz, in addition to the slowdown caused by the slower speed inside the material.

You probably wouldn't notice any decline in connection quality through walls of a normal thickness, though for a mouse, there might be enough lag to interfere with gaming.

Comment: *in addition to the slowdown caused by the slower speed inside the material* - you're kidding, right? Even with an unreal velocity factor of .8, 10 cm of plexiglas would cause a 'lag' of ~65 *pico*seconds - about as much time as is needed for the light from your monitor to reach the eye, or about 1% of a pixel's width (for 1080p60).